# Swift 4 Change nil jsonElement to an empty string

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

As per the title, I have had no luck with this, I have managed to have a small fix for nil elements by putting anything that could be nil into its own `if let` but I would like it to become an empty string rather than nil as I will need to use it later. (I think?)

```
if let studentID = jsonElement["S_ID"] as? String,
let firstName = jsonElement["FirstName"] as? String,
let surname = jsonElement["Surname"] as? String,
let displayPicture = jsonElement["StudentPicture"] as? String,
let dateOfBirth = jsonElement["DateofBirth"] as? String
{
    student.studentID = studentID
    student.firstName = firstName
    student.surname = surname
    student.displayPicture = displayPicture
    student.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
    //    student.father = father
    //    student.guardian = guardian
    //   student.keyPerson = keyPerson
}

if let mother = jsonElement["Mother"] as? String
{
    student.mother = mother
}
```

I'm very noob with iOS programming, pls be gentle. I have tried reading similar topics but couldn't get it to work.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `else` part for handling `nil` value.

```
if let mother = jsonElement["Mother"] as? String {
    student.mother = mother
} else {
    student.mother = ""
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just provide it a default value, e.g.:

```
student.studentID = (jsonElement["S_ID"] as? String) ?? ""
```

Read more in *Nil-Coalescing Operator* section of *[Basic Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)* in Swift:

> The nil-coalescing operator `(a ?? b)` unwraps an optional `a` if it contains a value, or returns a default value `b` if a is `nil`. **The expression `a` is always of an optional type.** The expression `b` must match the type that is stored inside `a`.